# Is it a good idea to resize a dynamic array in C++ on a Microcontroller

Tags: c++, arrays

I am building a model railroad crossing gate signal and am working on the micro controller code to make it function. I have run into an issue that has me questioning my methodology.

I am reading RFID tags (every car has one inside it), once the train triggers entry into the crossing gate zone, and putting the tag numbers into an array. The problem is that array will most likely always need to be re-sized as not every train has the same number of cars, and therefore the same number of RFID tags. I need to capture the last cars tag, as I need to monitor for that tag from the exit zone RFID reader so I know when to close the gates and shut the flashers off. Additionally, I could just count the cars as a new tag is discovered and the just match the count in the exit zone, thereby not needing the array.

Is there a more efficient way to do this besides and array? I am a C# guy so not all that familiar with how to handle in C++, with pointers and all that comes with that.

Another thought was to abandon the array and just replace a tagID variable with each tag read, thinking the last cars tag will be in the variable all the time, and match the entry and exit car count, that might be the simplest solution.

Thoughts on best approach?

Comment: I am a micro controller programmer and I do use c++.....but I find it unwise to use dynamic allocation with micro controllers....one way to get around this is to just define your array to take up the rest of the available memory (that way it would act the same up until the point where dynamic allocation would fail anyways)...

Comment: If there's a reasonable maximum number of cars, you can get space for it once and not worry about it resizing. Though a solution where you don't need the array would be better. You just need to identify each train right?

Comment: 1) use emulation before low-level hardware experiments - if it's possible 2)  Neither C++ nor C have dynamic arrays. Dynamic array is a run-time artifact using pointer magic.  3) If you use C++, use std::vector, choose a compiler options wisely..  and here's an article for you http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4438660/Modern-C--in-embedded-systems---Part-1--Myth-and-Reality

Comment: I thought someone would opine on just rewriting the one tag variable with the last read tag ID, that seems simplest method as once tags stop being read on entering the zone, the variable should have the last cars tag ID stored in it.

Comment: @dinotom pool allocator?

Comment: If all you care about is last in, last out than by all means, watch for the last tag. Or count tags in and decrement tags out. But for all that is holy, never miss a tag.

Comment: The question is unclear to me - the title and much of the text focus on a dynamic array to store some indeterminate number of IDs, but some of the question and a mention in the comments is basically asking if it's OK to simply store and look for the last car's ID.  So what are you asking about, and if storing/looking for the last car's ID will solve your problem, then what is your question about that?

Comment: @MichaelBurr... The post outlined three potential solutions, one of which was just storing tags to capture the last tag as well as array usage or a combination of both. The question asks what best approach is for C++ and so far has produced some intelligent answers.

Comment: I edited the post title to be clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a real-world railway crossing this ultimately can affect peoples' safety.  Although this is just a model, it may be a good exercise to get you thinking about the types of things you might encounter in the real world (since that's just a scaled-up version with bigger consequences).

I would recommend:

- Make the code as simple as possible;
- Provide internal verification measures to ensure assumptions match reality;
- Have defined recovery procedures to handle when the above verifications fail;
- Write unit tests to verify all edge-cases and out-of-mode operation (if you have an obsessive nature).

It is not recommended to use dynamic memory in a microcontroller environment unless you really know what you're doing.  Running out of memory and crashing due to unintended fragmentation is a very real problem.

One simple approach is to record the first tag, the last tag, and the number of tags.  That way you can do some sanity check on the start and exit carriages and ensure the same number of carriages exited as entered.  If not, enter some alarm recovery state where you log the issue and perhaps use some timeout or other detection to determine it's safe to raise the arm.

Another approach would be to make a static array that's enough to store tags for more carriages than can physically fit between the two detectors, and use it as a ring buffer.  That way you can validate every carriage as it leaves the crossing.

If you really feel the need to use dynamic memory, go ahead.  But consider that if such a system could fail due to runaway allocation, then any static array solution might also fail in that scenario.  And you may want to rethink your approach.

Comment: Nice answer, but I don't see how a model railroad can hurt anyone. :P

Comment: Great thought. I thought about doing both, counting the tags read as well as storing the tagID's in a variable, so the last cars tag is always the last one in the variable and then in the exit zone checking the passed car count and the tagID, only closing the gate when the count and ID match.

Comment: @Veedrac Clearly you've never seen Ant-Man

Comment: Hahaha oh I didn't actually see the 'model' bit.  But hey, if you're gonna engineer something...  Engineer it. =)

Comment: No harm in producing the world's first SIL3 model railroad. Go paranoid and minimalist anyway. Good practice for later.

Comment: @Veedrac I'm actually wondering how _model railroads_ could react on undefined behavior in your controlling program? It might arise that one of your locomotives is going completely out of control, overly accelerates at highest speed, derails and hits you hardly at your forehead. So far _"how a model railroad could hurt anyone"_. Nasal demons on top of course.

Comment: @dinotom That was mostly a joke. If you want to play in the European rail system with the 200+ km/h trains, you have some serious quality requirements on the software you can produce. To have a system that's involved in train switching, [you usually have to meet SIL3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_integrity_level), specifically EN 50128, and that is a far-from-trivial task. Anyway, if you write your code adhering to a real-world use-case, but not necessary as anal as EN 50128, you will probably come out a better real-world programmer.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid pointers and manually memory allocation you can use the class

```
std::vector
```

Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in size.

[You can learn more about it here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: `std::vector` allocates memory.  If you want to avoid memory allocation, you would not use it, unless you supplied a custom allocator that uses static storage.

Comment: to avoid memory allocation, just use `reserve`.

Comment: @wander `std::vector` might not be the best idea to use on a microcontroller environment.

Comment: Recommend an edit to make the link larger. Suggest stretching it out to the whole sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *crossing gate zone* should have a **finite number** of cars that can be accepted at a time. Doesn't it?

What you can do, is to implement some kind of a fixed sized queue based on a `std::array<tagId,MAX_SLOTS>`, and keep the actually available incoming slot index.

Comment: There can only be so many cars in the zone, but a trains length is not limited to the road crossing zone area.

Answer (score 0):

I would do some thing like this:

```
template<class T, size_t max>
class ResizeableArray{
    T array[max];
    size_t end;
  public:
    void addLast(T value){
      array[end] = value;
      end++;  //Maybe check before you do this
    }
    size_t size(){
      return end;
    }
    T operator[](size_t index){
      return array[index];  //Maybe do a check here?
    }
    void RemoveLast(){
      end--;
      array[end].~T();  //Destroy the object
    }
};
```

And then later you can use like this:

```
ResizeableArray<TrainCar,32> cars;  //Max size of 32
cars.addLast(TrainCar());
cars.addLast(TrainCar());
cars.addLast(TrainCar());
cars.addLast(TrainCar());
if (cars[1].someMethod())
  doSomthing();
```

The real bonus is that using this method there is **no** dynamic memory initialization, which I would definitely suggest if you are on a micro.  The other nice thing is it acts (somewhat) like a built in list holder.  If you wanted more functionality you could add it.

Comment: If elements of the array are destroyed via calls to `RemoveLast` and never reinitialized you will encounter undefined behavior when the array is destroyed.

Comment: @Cap Well because this is a statically defined thing it never will be destroyed

Comment: A solution that exhibits undefined behavior isn't a solution it's a defect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is basically to make sure all the cars that enter the zone also exit.

Counting them alone feels inadequate, in case one is double counted at the exit, and the last car happens to get left behind in the zone.

Depending on the length of the rfid, it might be OK to count them and XOR all the tags. This would give you some confidence that you've got the same cars coming out as went in.